# jQuery scrollTop to top of container div

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I am using the excellent accordion menu provided by Ian Flynn of RocketMill: http://www.rocketmill.co.uk/create-accordian-boxes-with-a-rotating-arrow-using-css-jquery

This has worked well for me in the past, but I have a new client that leans towards the **verbose.** This presents a problem when the user attempts to click on their next desired accordion link. The accordion works correctly, but the hyperbolic amount of content shoots off of the page, presenting an obvious usability issue.

What I want to do is to reconcile the top of the active (just clicked on) "menuTitle" div with the top of its parent, the "content" div.

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="menuTitle">
        <strong>Title 1&hellip;</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="menuContent"> <!-- Sliding content box -->
        <h5>Sub-title 1</h5>
        <p>Content</p>
    </div> <!-- End of div class="menuContent" -->
<!-- THE ABOVE SEVEN LINES REPEAT FOR EACH FOLD OF THE ACCORDION -->
</div> <!-- End of div id="content" -->
```

I have been working on this for about three days and have consulted many, many sites, jQuery guides, and whisky. I am not a jQuery expert. Please help!

Oh… I made a jsFiddle. My first: http://jsfiddle.net/Parapluie/CRXX8/

Comment: Have you tried calling `$(this).slideUp('normal');` on the clicked element? [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JWells/g26GD/)

Comment: J., I don't see the difference between your results and mine. I tried it in the most recent versions of Chrome, Safari, and FF.

The key is they must reconcile so that users can see the first line of the desired div (accordion fold) at the top of the parent div.

Comment: The difference is - mine hides the menuTitle text after click. To place the slideDown element where the menuTitle was, you should be able offset the margin-top by the padding-top of same, which would position that text at the same place as the menuTitle.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, J., I worry though that we may be talking at cross-purposes. Sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: My answer is uppdated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, if i understand what you want..

http://jsfiddle.net/CRXX8/4/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#content .menuTitle').on('click',function() {
        $('#content .menuTitle').removeClass('on'); // "closes" the closing menu arrow
        $('#content .menuContent').slideUp('normal'); // slide-closes the closing div
        if($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {
            $(this).addClass('on'); // "opens" the opening menu arrow
            $(this).next().slideDown('normal',function(){
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this).prev().offset().top}, {queue: false,duration:250, easing: 'swing'}); // on complete slidedown, scroll the clicked .menuTitle to top of page
            });// slide-opens the opening div
        }
    }); // end of click event
}); // end of ready
```

**UPDATE:**

As your called elements are wraped in a div called `'#focusWide'`, you dont have to scrollTop `html,body`, you have to scrollTop the wraper div `'#focusWide'` and use `position().top` istead of `offset().top`. And i add more `'11px'` (half of wraper div padding).

```
$('#focusWide').animate({scrollTop:$(this).prev().position().top + 11 + 'px'}, {queue: false,duration:250, easing: 'swing'});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CUu7h/2/

Comment: This works too, LGVentura, thanks much. Mhu was first under the wire, but I will compare and contrast while implementing.

Comment: This doesn't work when I transport it to my site. See comment on Mhu's answer.

Comment: Correction to my last comment. When I post LGVentura's javascript into the fiddle, it DOES work with the extra divs surrounding the accordion; however, when I add the CSS, it breaks. Here is a jsFiddle with the additional CSS in place: http://jsfiddle.net/Parapluie/CUu7h/1/

Comment: Hi, i understand what you need. I updated my answer, please read my explanation.

Comment: Implemented in situ and WORKING! Thank you so much, Luis. I am approving this answer. I will also post the finished site here, after the launch later in the summer. Thanks to all who helped on this.

Answer (score 0):

I use the function shown below, which works great in most cases. Just make sure the container/wrapper is scrollable (using `overflow-y:auto`). See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CRXX8/3/)

```
function scrollIntoView(oElement, sContainer, fnCallback) {
    var oContainer, nContainerTop, nContainerBottom, nElemHeight, nElemTop, nElemBottom;

    if (!oElement || oElement.length <= 0) {
        return;
    }

    oContainer = (typeof sContainer == "object" ? sContainer : $(sContainer));
    nContainerTop = oContainer.scrollTop();
    nContainerBottom = nContainerTop + oContainer.height();
    nElemHeight = oElement.height() || 25;
    nElemTop = oElement[0].offsetTop - 50;
    nElemBottom = nElemTop + nElemHeight + 100;
    if ((nElemTop < nContainerTop) || (nElemHeight >= $(sContainer).height())) {
        oContainer.animate({ scrollTop: nElemTop }, { duration: "fast", complete: fnCallback });
    }
    else if (nElemBottom > nContainerBottom) {
        oContainer.animate({ scrollTop: (nElemBottom - $(sContainer).height()) }, { duration: "fast", complete: fnCallback });
    }
    else if (fnCallback) {
        fnCallback();
    }
}
```

Comment: Mhu, it's mhusic to my eyes! Thank you so very much. I will be finishing that bottle of whisky tonight in a very different spirit, and implementing this tomorrow, happily.

Comment: Okay. I think we're on the road, but not quite there. When I add this to my site code, it does not perform as in jsFiddle. If I wrap the html in Mhu's fiddle with the same divs as my site, then the fiddle breaks. Here is a new sample: http://jsfiddle.net/Parapluie/AwWm7/ The same thing happens in LGVentura's code. What are your thoughts?

Comment: You always need to make sure the container is scrollable (has a scrollbar). For example with fixed height: http://jsfiddle.net/AwWm7/1/